# Unable to access modal-dialogue in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to access modal-dialogue using cypress, what usually happens is that when you access the base Url, after 5-6 seconds, it will navigate user to modal-dialogue , where user have to login himself.

following is the class name of dialog:

```
<div class = "modal-dialog">
```

and I am trying to get access of email address field:

**Check Screenshot of the page**

[image: screenshot of the authentication dialog and the devtools output]

While using the following code:

```
describe('Login', function(){
    it('Login Successfully', function(){
        const urlRedirects = [];
        cy.visit('https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase')
        cy.get('.modal-dialog').should('be.visible').then(($dialog)=>{
      cy.wrap($dialog).find('#signInFormUsername').click()
      });
        })
        
    })
```

for which I am getting following error:

```
Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

  > Blocked a frame with origin "https://app.staging.showcare.io" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:

> https://showcare.io

A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new URL which does not match the origin policy above.

A new URL does not match the origin policy if the 'protocol', 'port' (if specified), and/or 'host' (unless of the same superdomain) are different.

Cypress does not allow you to navigate to a different origin URL within a single test.

You may need to restructure some of your test code to avoid this problem.

Alternatively you can also disable Chrome Web Security in Chromium-based browsers which will turn off this restriction by setting { chromeWebSecurity: false } in cypress.json.
```

Can someone please help me out?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This test works

```js
cy.visit('https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase/login')
cy.get('.modal-dialog').should('be.visible')
cy.get('#signInFormUsername', { timeout: 10000 }).eq(0)
  .click({ force: true })
```

There is a warning that there are two `#signInFormUsername`, so add `.eq(0)` to ensure you click the right one.

Also, the control has a parent with CSS `display: none`, so `{ force: true }` is needed on the `.click()`.

Please note, you will have to restart Cypress test runner after setting `"chromeWebSecurity": false`.

---

The full login sequence

```js
cy.visit('https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase/login')

cy.get('.modal-dialog').should('be.visible')

cy.get('#signInFormUsername', { timeout: 10000 }).eq(0)
  .type('userName', { force: true })

cy.get('#signInFormPassword').eq(0)
  .type('password', { force: true })

cy.get('[name="signInSubmitButton"]').eq(0)
  .click({ force: true })
```

---

The page URL of the login form is (the beginning part)

```html
https://vep-staging.auth...amazoncognito.com/login?...&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.staging.showcare.io%2Fproduct-showcase&...
```

and that `redirect_uri` parameter should send you back to `https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase` after successful login.

If not, you can do the login part in a `beforeEach()` and then visit the main page in the test. A login token should be stored for you by the login step.

Also, wrap the code in a `cy.session()` to do the login just once, and preserve the token for all tests (same as happens with a user logging in and doing various things in a session.

The full test,

```js
Cypress.config('experimentalSessionSupport', true)  // set this flag

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('mySession', () => {

    // preserve the login across all tests

    cy.visit('https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase/login')
    cy.get('.modal-dialog').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('#signInFormUsername', { timeout: 10000 }).eq(0)
  .    type('userName', { force: true })
    cy.get('#signInFormPassword').eq(0)
      .type('password', { force: true })
    cy.get('[name="signInSubmitButton"]').eq(0)
      .click({ force: true })
  })
})

it('tests the app main page after login', () => {

  // should be logged in here, so visit main page
  cy.visit('https://app.staging.showcare.io/product-showcase') 

  // test the main page, e.g 
  cy.get('nav').contains('Homepage')
})
```

Comment: Man, How can I thank you... Seriously... Thank you really really much...

Comment: but I have another question, now after signing in, I have to jump back to same url, which I have used in cy.visit, what should I do? @Vispo
Do I need to go again with cy.get access.

Comment: I have a different domain so I have to use multiple `describe` blocks. so what can I do?

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya - you are mistaken - you only need multiple `it` not multiple `describe`

Comment: @Vispo If I use multiple it will give me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `cypress.json` file and write:

```js
{
  chromeWebSecurity: false
}
```

This will disable cross-origin errors.

Comment: Hey @Alapan Das I have tried it, its still not working.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the error that you are getting. And also add your `cypress.json ` file.