# Unable to navigate from button after clicking on it - Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to click on 'Exhibitor Access' showing in screenshot, Test Runner is showing 'click' action, but click is not happening at all, Check screenshot.

[image]

Please Can someone help me out on this, as I am stuck, I am using following strategy for this:

```
cy.get('a').eq(0).realClick()
```

As you may check in Test Runner, click is happening, but it is not navigating anywhere.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the click happens too soon (Cypress shows partial page).

Perhaps add a check for some text,

```js
cy.contains('Please select which exhibiter booth you want to process')
cy.contains('a', 'Exhibitor Access').realClick()
```

Comment: No Mihi, I want to click on 'Exhibitor Access' button only. Thats it.

Comment: Why? You must ensure that your page will not be loaded. It makes no sense.

Comment: before that clicking action, I am using wait(6000), and I think it is quite enough, also this is just one case, there is a case, where user have no exhibitor booths, what will i do then?

Comment: What will you do? That depends on what the page looks like in that state - provide that info, can answer that question.

Comment: And so 6 seconds wait but Cypress still does not see the full page? How can it be enough time? Is there something blocking the page load. You should be trying things instead of finding reasons why it cannot work.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. Its intend behaviour. Right now, what happening is that after login , network is showing me 401 i.e. 'Unauthorized error', which is not showing any products down there.

Comment: See [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69066845/16864887), use `cy.session()` to maintain login status.