# I don't want to clear cashe and cookies in cypress

Tags: api, local-storage, cypress, session-cookies, session-storage

I have tried many but have not been successful, please help me with the example. I have put all code here you can also try it on your system.

I am testing registration flow using cypress. and I don't want to clear cache/cookies before each test. can anyone help me?

This is my test file, and the first describe block is to send OTP for entered email. the second one is to create a temporary email and save OTP into a JSON file for letter use. and the third one is for verifying OTP using API. but when I use the same URL and enter an email which OTP verified by API it shows `500 Internal server error`

```
const faker = require("faker");
const firstName = faker.Name.firstName();
const lastName = faker.Name.lastName();
const email = firstName + "@mailinator.com";

describe('My Test Suite', function () {
  it('Otp Test', function () {
    cy.visit('https://outsized.site/')
    cy.get('.css-jqdzg6-commonButtonStyle > canvas', { timeout: 30000 }).click()
    cy.get('#email').type(email.toLocaleLowerCase())
    cy.get('.ant-btn').click()
    cy.fixture('data1').then((profile) => {
      profile.FreelancerName = firstName.toLocaleLowerCase()
      profile.FreelancerEmail = email.toLocaleLowerCase()
      cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/data1.json", profile)
      cy.wait(2000)
    })
  })
})

context('My Test Suite', function () {
  it('Otp Test', function () {
    cy.visit('https://www.mailinator.com/')
    cy.fixture("data1.json").then(profile => {
      cy.get("#addOverlay").type(profile.FreelancerName)
    })
    cy.get("#go-to-public").click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.contains('table tbody tr', 'OTP').click()  // find the right email

    cy.get('#html_msg_body')  // iframe
      .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')  // wait for loading
      .then(console.log)  // works with this but errors without - totally weird
      .wait(0)
      .find("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > h2")
      .then($h2 => {
        const OTP = $h2.text()
        cy.fixture("data1.json").then(profile => {
          profile.OTP = OTP
          cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/data1.json", profile);
        })
      })
  })
})

context('My Test Suite', function () {
  it('Otp Test', function () {
    cy.fixture('data1').then((profile) => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.outsized.site/graphql',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        body:
          'mutation { verifyEmailOtp(email: "' + profile.FreelancerName + '@mailinator.com", otp: ' + profile.OTP + '){ message } }'
      })
    })
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.fixture("data1.json").then(profile => {
      cy.visit("https://outsized.site")
      cy.wait(5000)
      //cy.visit(profile.url+profile.FreelancerName+"%40"+"mailinator.com")
      cy.get('.css-jqdzg6-commonButtonStyle > canvas', { timeout: 30000 }).click()
      cy.get('#email').type(profile.FreelancerEmail)
      cy.get('.ant-btn').click()
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.outsized.site/graphql',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        body:
          'mutation { addNewEmail(email: "' + profile.FreelancerName + '@mailinator.com"){ message } }'
      })
      cy.get('.ant-btn').click()
    })
  })
})
```

`500 Internal server error` get because cypress has clear cache and cookies before each test.

Comment: You need to simplify a bit, as it stands the code is not easy to follow. Where does the the error occur? Why do you think it's related to cookie cleardown? The error status code 500 not consistent with that.

Comment: As I said, the first describe block is to send OTP for entered email. the second one is to create a temporary email and save OTP into a JSON file for a letter use. and the third one is for verifying OTP using API. after I use the same URL and enter an email which OTP verified by API it shows 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 2):

There's a relatively new command `cy.session()` ([docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)) that preserves cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage. Not sure if that includes "cache", in fact I don't know what you refer to there.

The way it works is you can add it into a `beforeEach()` so it gets called by each test, but it only calls the code inside once (first test), then for subsequent calls it retains and restores the values from the above stores that were set during the first test.

There's an example here [Unable to access modal-dialogue in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69066845/16791505) which is simpler than the examples in the official documents.

The basic pattern is worth repeating

```js
Cypress.config('experimentalSessionSupport', true)  // set this flag

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('mySession', () => {

    // code that sets cookies, only called once
    // thereafter same cookies, localstorage, sessionStorage
    // are preserved for future test

  })
})
```

I can't really tell what code you need from your sample above, but I'm sure you know already.

Comment: I have multiple domains so I need to use different `describe` blocks. so what can I do?

Comment: Maybe that's why you get `500 Internal server error`, which is not a status code you'd get if you were loosing credentials from a cookie. That would give you `401 (Unauthorized) status code`.

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: The multiple domains are not related to the `describe` blocks, so yes just add it in and see if fixes it.

Comment: I can't understand. can you describe?